# Twitter Bootstrap: make specific span not responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I do want my website to stay responsive, the sidebar should still go under the content when the screen is too small, but there's a few `span*` classes I'm using that I don't want going to 100% width when the screen is too small. Is there a way I can still use the `span*` class (it's a really easy way to position things) but explicitly say that they should not be responsive; either on the container, or row, or each span, whatever works.

Comment: Use `row` class instead of `row-fluid`?

Comment: @adaam That doesn't seem to work, and I'm not sure why you think it would?

Comment: Edit: just copy the non responsive spans from the non responsive bootstrap and rename span to something like "span-nr" and use that instead?

Comment: @Melbourne2991 This definitely works. I was kind of hoping for a supported way of doing it, but I guess it's not a common thing to do. ty

Answer (score 0):

a bit short for explanation, code is missing.

have you tried using selector: `span[class*="span"]{}`  to filter the class you want ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have it both ways. 
Either your bootstrap grid is responsive or it isn't.

This is because all bootstrap knows is whether or not the responsive initialization snippet has been called. If it has, then it changes the spans to make them responsive.

If you want a way around this, I would copy the styles from the span class that you want applied to your unresponsive sections and then make a new class with those styles.

So, if you wanted to make an additional unresponsive `.span3` you could just copy the relevant styles and make your own classes. You would need to set the width, float, and margins. In this case `width: 220px;`, `float: left;` , and add a `.margin-right: 20px;`. The widths can be found in bootstrap.css file.

I also attached a fiddle for reference -- http://jsfiddle.net/c86kE/